# IEnumerator Compiler error

Tags: c#

Code

```
    [DebuggerHidden]
private IEnumerator set_vehicle_upgrade(int wid, int upid)
{
    Master.set_vehicle_upgrade.c__Iterator22 set_vehicle_upgradec__Iterator = new Master.set_vehicle_upgrade.c__Iterator22();
    set_vehicle_upgradec__Iterator.upid = upid;
    set_vehicle_upgradec__Iterator.wid = wid;
    set_vehicle_upgradec__Iterator.upid = upid;
    set_vehicle_upgradec__Iterator.wid = wid;
    set_vehicle_upgradec__Iterator.f__this = this;
    return set_vehicle_upgradec__Iterator;
}
```

why this error happen at line `Master.set_vehicle_upgrade.c__Iterator22;`  errors: `

> new Master.set_vehicle_upgrade.c__Iterator22();`
>   error is Error  94  'Master.set_vehicle_upgrade(int, int)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'  C:\Users\user\Desktop\assembly\Master.cs    828 10  Assembly-CSharp

and

> Error  96  'Master.set_vehicle_upgrade(int, int)' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'  C:\Users\user\Desktop\assembly\Master.cs    828 88  Assembly-CSharp

Comment: Please share more code - what are the lines in question?  What happens in `line 94` in `Master.cs` file? And what in `line 88` (Or is it `828`?)? Also, note that your variable naming is not inconvention and hard to read. In C# the convention is `cSetVehicleUpgradeIterator` instead of `set_vehicle_upgradec__Iterator`

Comment: Also what is the code for the `c'tor` of `c__Iterator22 class`?

Comment: It happens because, exactly as the error message states, `'Master.set_vehicle_upgrade` is a method, so `new Master.set_vehicle_upgrade.c__Iterator22()` is not a legal expression as `set_vehicle_upgrade` has no members. My psychic debugging skills tell me this is the output of a code generator or decompiler that has gotten confused and is not properly disambiguating names.